# I Have a horizontal recyclerview with images in it but they are way too far from each other

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Ok so I have a horizontal recycler view and I'm putting images into it but they are way too far from each other how could I fix it?

***Layout code where I have my image***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="106dp"
        android:layout_height="171dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***Layout code where I have the recycler view***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="416dp"
        android:layout_height="174dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Try to use wrap_content in recyclerView

Comment: try removing `android:layout_marginStart="19dp"` and  `android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"` from  `ImageView`

Comment: No, none of those worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your constraintLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent" to

> android:layout_width="wrap_content"

change your recyclerView android:layout_width="416dp" to

> android:layout_width="match_parent"